# devise "user_signed_in?" method in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I have a controller action which uses devise's "**user_signed_in?**" as a condition. The action looks like this:

```
 def show           
   if user_signed_in?
     #do stuff
   end
 end
```

But when I am testing this action in RSpec, the tests are failing because the code inside the if block never gets executed. Is there any way to stub the "**user_signed_in?**" method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not executed because the user is probably not signed in.
To sign in a devise user in rspec, have this in `spec/support/controller_macros.rb`.

```
module ControllerMacros
    def login_user
      before(:each) do
        @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        user.confirm! #if you are using the "confirmable" module
        sign_in user
      end
    end
end
```

In `spec/rails_helper.rb` have this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

Then in your controller spec:

```
describe MyController do 
  login_user
  ....
end
```

Comment: No, I have the user logged in. The code that you have shown, is already there in my app.

Comment: Oops. Looks like I forgot to skip the before filters. They were the ones causing problems. Sorry, I'm new to this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This gives me a `method_missing': undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::PagesController:Class (NoMethodError)
 from /home/klaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-4-2-7/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:28:in `block in <module:ControllerHelpers>'
Using RSpec 3.5 and Devise 4.2.0

Answer (score 2):

You could mock `user_signed_in?` method like this:

```rb
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(Devise::Controllers::Helpers).to receive(:user_signed_in?).and_return(false)
end
```